# Rails 3 + Devise: updating a database attribute when signing in and out

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to change the status attribute in my users table to "Online" or "Offline" whenever a user signs in or out.
I created my own sessions controller by adding an update_attribute to the relevant methods:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def sign_out_and_redirect(resource_or_scope)
    current_user.update_attribute(:status, "Offline" )
    scope = Devise::Mapping.find_scope!(resource_or_scope)
    Devise.sign_out_all_scopes ? sign_out : sign_out(scope)
    redirect_for_sign_out(scope)
  end

  def redirect_for_sign_out(scope)
    redirect_to after_sign_out_path_for(scope)    
  end

  def sign_in_and_redirect(resource_or_scope, *args)
    options  = args.extract_options!
    scope    = Devise::Mapping.find_scope!(resource_or_scope)
    resource = args.last || resource_or_scope

    if warden.user(scope) == resource
      expire_session_data_after_sign_in!
    else
      sign_in(scope, resource, options)
    end

    current_user.update_attribute(:status, "Online" )

    redirect_for_sign_in(scope, resource)
  end

  def redirect_for_sign_in(scope, resource)
    redirect_to stored_location_for(scope) || after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  end

end
```

and for the following I get an undefined method error:

```
Devise.sign_out_all_scopes

expire_session_data_after_sign_in!
```

how do I fix this?

When I remove the first undefined method I only have:

```
sign_out(scope)
```

and then it works for signing out. But I don't want to delete the expression for signing in.

what should I do? Is there maybe another way to keep track of an users online status?

Answer (score 0):

Just solved my problem by just putting everything from the sessions_controller.rb to a helper/sessions_helper.rb and adding the methods sign_out_all_scopes and expire_session_data_after_sign_in! from the Devise API to the helper.

Comment: Alright I thought I solved my problem but it only worked a couple of times...
after a while it stopped working and the status attribute is nil after a new user is created or doesn't want to change when a user signs in or out